# Load and show binary image in AngularJS and html by address

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, image, dropzone.js

I use Dropzone image uploader. This plugin fortunately uploaded my images in binary format and I like it. And also move file uploaded in my "/upload" folder perfectly but without extension. I need to show the image uploaded, from upload folder in my HTML page by different extension. This is a screenshot of my upload folder:

[image]

How can I read and show the images by their address in  tag?
The upload folder is 2 previews directory from my HTML file. How can I address in  ?

This is my HTML uploader:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="XYZ123">
<form id="upload-widget" method="post" action="/upload" class="dropzone">
     <div class="fallback">
        <input name="file" type="file" />
     </div>
</form>
```

This is my Dropzone uploader js code:

```
Dropzone.options.uploadWidget = {
    paramName: 'file',
    maxFilesize: 2, // MB
    maxFiles: 1,
    dictDefaultMessage: 'Drag an image here to upload, or click to select one',
    headers: {
      'x-csrf-token': document.querySelectorAll('meta[name=csrf-token]')[0].getAttributeNode('content').value,
    },
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    init: function() {
      this.on('success', function( file, resp ){
        console.log( file );
        console.log( resp );
      });
      this.on('thumbnail', function(file) {
        if ( file.width < 20 || file.height < 20  ) {
          file.rejectDimensions();
        } else {
          file.acceptDimensions();
        }
      });
    },
    accept: function(file, done) {
      file.acceptDimensions = done;
      file.rejectDimensions = function() {
        done('The image must be at least 20 x 20')
      };
    }
  };
```

And I didn`t use my controllers for this.

Comment: Post your HTML and controller code.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: May help http://jsfiddle.net/kkhxsgLu/2/